# How to get most important feature coefficients when i used pipeline to preprocess, train and test the linear svc?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am using a LinearSVC, i pre-processed the numeric and categorical data using column transformer,then used pipeline. I used GridSearchCV to get the best parameters for the model which i later put into the pipeline as you can see.
I fit,tested and got the score as well but i want to know the most important feature coefficients.

So far, i have tried " clf.coef_ " as the classifier step is named as clf in the pipeline but i get a message saying clf not defined.
I also tried gridf.coef_,pipefinal.steps[1].coef_ but nothing worked.
So any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
preprocessing=ColumnTransformer([('hot',OneHotEncoder(),categ),('scale',StandardScaler(),num)],n_jobs=-1)
pipefinal=Pipeline([('pre',preprocessing),('clf',LinearSVC(max_iter=100000,C=0.1))])
gridf=GridSearchCV(pipefinal,param_grid={},cv=10)
gridf.fit(X_train,y_train)
gridf.score(X_val,y_val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` will make the best estimator available through its `best_estimator_` attribute after you have called the `fit()` method. Since your estimator is a `Pipeline` object, you have to further subscript it to access the classifier. Then, you can access its `coef_` attribute. In your case, that would be:

```py
gridf.best_estimator_['clf'].coef_
```